# How to create MutableSharedFlow in Kotlin Coroutines simillar to PublishSubject from RxJava?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Is there an equivalent of `PublishSubject` from RxJava in Kotlin Coroutines library?

Channels cannot be a replacement for `PublishSubject` since they do not publish values to multiple collectors (each value can be collected by a single collector only). Even `MutableSharedFlow` that supports multiple collectors, still does not allow emitting values without waiting for collectors to finish processing previous values. How can we create a flow with functionality similar to the `PublishSubject`?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will create a `Flow` equivalent to the `PublishSubject`:

```kotlin
fun <T> publishFlow(): MutableSharedFlow<T> {
    return MutableSharedFlow(
        replay = 0,
        extraBufferCapacity = Int.MAX_VALUE
    )
}
```

The main attributes of the PublishSubject are that it does not replay old values to new observers, and still allows to publish new values/events without waiting for the observers to handle them. So this functionality can be achieved with `MutableSharedFlow` by specifying `replay = 0`  for preventing new collectors from collecting old values, and `extraBufferCapacity = Int.MAX_VALUE` to allow publishing new values without waiting for busy collectors to finish collecting previous values.

One can add the following `forceEmit` function to be called instead of `tryEmit`, to ensure that the value is actually emitted:

```kotlin
fun <T> MutableSharedFlow<T>.forceEmit(value: T) {
    val emitted = tryEmit(value)
    check(emitted){ "Failed to emit into shared flow." }
}
```

Since we have a buffer with `MAX_VALUE` capacity, this `forceEmit` function should never fail if we use it with our `publishFlow`. If the flow will be replaced somehow with a different flow that does not support emitting without suspending, we will get an exception and will know to handle the case where the buffer is full and one cannot emit without suspending.

Notice that having a buffer of `MAX_VALUE` capacity may cause high consumption of memory if the collection of values by the collectors takes a long time, so it is more suitable for cases where the collectors perform a short synchronous operation (similarly to RxJava observers).